# Near People With Core Location

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, frameworks, core-location

I am wondering if there is some way to find people that are near you using data supplied by the Core Location Framework.  If you can get the other person's CLLocation's description attribute, I assume there must be some way to compare this in terms of location to your location.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Location can only gather location data from the device it is running on, so it won't be able to get location information from other devices. Instead you want to implement some centralized server to handle the location data of all devices using an app, and let individual devices talk to the server for this information.

Comment: Hi LokiSnake: Thanks for your help.  So, would I store CLLocation's description attribute in the database, or something else?  And then once I get this data from the database, how can I see if it is within x meters of the current user?

Comment: I see it working this way:
You'd put all the info into some data format on a server. A client would submit its location to the server, and the server can also return the closest n neighbors. This can be done with some computational geometry algorithms.

Hope this helps.